# lowercase to uppercase in C++

Tags: c++, uppercase, lowercase

note that I am not asking what are the methods to convert lowercase letters to UPPERCASE letters in C++ but instead, I want to know which of these two methods in the codes below (Upper1 and Upper2) are better than the other one and what's the reason, programming wise.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale> //Upper2 requires this module

using namespace std;

void Upper1(string &inputStr);
void Upper2(string &inputStr);

int main(){

    string test1 = "ABcdefgHIjklmno3434dfsdf3434PQRStuvwxyz";
    string test2 = "ABcdefgHIjklmnoPQRStuvwxyz";

    Upper1(test1);
    cout << endl << endl << "test1 (Upper1): ";
    for (int i = 0; i < test1.length(); i++){
        cout << test1[i] << " ";
    }


    Upper2(test2);
    cout << endl << endl << "test2 (Upper2): ";
    for (int i = 0; i < test2.length(); i++){
        cout << test2[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}

void Upper1(string &test1){

    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++){ 
        if (test1[i] > 96 && test1[i] <123){ //convert only those of lowercase letters
            test1[i] = (char)(test1[i]-(char)32);
        }

    }
}

void Upper2(string &test2){

    locale loc;

    for (size_t i=0; i<test2.length(); ++i)
        test2[i] = toupper(test2[i],loc);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between the two proposed solutions is that
`Upper2` sort of works, regardless of the platform; `Upper1`
makes assumptions concerning the encoding, and doesn't work on
any modern platform that I know of.  (It assumes ASCII, and
ASCII is, for all intents and purposes, dead.)

Of course, neither really works, for two simple reasons: the
first is that most modern machines use a multibyte encoding
(UTF-8), so you cannot convert a string from lower to upper one
byte at a time.  The second is because there is not, generally
speaking, a one to one relationship of lower to upper: the
classical example is `'ß'`, whose upper case equivalent is the
two character string `"SS"`.  Still, for a somewhat simplistic
definition of the function, and a single byte encoding like ISO
8859-1 (probably the most widely used in the recent past),
`Upper2` will do a reasonably good job (provided there is no `'ß'`
in the input), adequate for many uses, whereas `Upper1` will fail lamentably.

Comment: you pointed out some good points, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The usage of toupper won't make sense if you have letters from other languages than English A-Z alphabet, e.g. the Germanic ä, ö or ü, and various accented letters in French/Spanish, and of course, if the input is a "germano-latin" language at all, for example Russian. [As pointed out by James, that may require Unicode parsing, which is a whole new ballgame altogether, tho']

Obviously, the first function is also hard-coded to convert the 27 first characters of the input, which is bad coding because the function shouldn't rely on the size of the string - particularly not since "std::string" does have a length in the first place!

Comment: thanks for the explanations :) I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

1. *toupper()* can handle non-ASCII character
2. Syntax wise, *Upper2()* is less error-prone
3. Not too sure about this, but i think *toupper()* is slower

Comment: Why do you think 3?  (It is obviously implementation dependent, and I've not done actual measurements in over 20 years, but when I did measure, `toupper` was significantly faster.)